# Cast boxed object to typeof(object)

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting, boxing

I have the following POCO classes

```
public interface IObject
{
    Guid Uid { get; set; }
}

public class Boo : IObject
{
    public Guid Uid { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IObject
{
    public Guid Uid { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to write a generic method to insert any type of object into the database where the type inherit from `IObject`. I am using the following method for that (with ServiceStackOrmLite underneath):

```
public interface IDataAccess
{
    IDbConnection GetConnection();

    Boolean InsertObject<T>(T newObj, IDbConnection connection) where T : IDataObject, new();
}
```

Trying to insert each object separately works as follow :

```
public static Boolean AddFoo(this Foo foo)
{
    // DataProvider is initiated using an implementation of IDataAccess
    return DataProvider.InsertObject(foo, DataProvider.GetConnection());
}
```

**Question :**

I am trying to use the following method as a valid one for both but it fails. The syntax is wrong but consider it as a pseudo code. How can I acheive that? `obj` will be a boxed `Foo` or `Boo` instance

```
public static Boolean AddObject(this IObject obj)
{
    Type objectType = obj.GetType();
    return DataProvider.InsertObject(obj as objectType, DataProvider.GetConnection());
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "boxed object"; if it was an object, it wouldn't be boxed. And any class / struct / interface / delegate / etc will cast to `object`... neither `Foo` nor `Boo` will ***ever*** be boxed. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Since `DataProvider.InsertObject` accepts evey `IDataObject`, why bother? Why not just call: `return DataProvider.InsertObject(obj, DataProvider.GetConnection());`

Comment: @MartinMulder presumably `InsertObject` uses the `T` internally. That would be a mistake, IMO, but there we go.

Comment: Is the `IDataObject` in the `AddObject` method a typo for the same `IObject` interface? or is that unrelated?

Comment: @MarcGravell: I edited the question. IDataObject was corrected to IObject just a typing mistake. I also mean a `Foo` or `Boo` object instance boxed into an IObject variable, presumebly I dont know if `Foo` or `Boo` is the correct concrete type

Comment: @MartinMulder: There will be an error that ojb must have a public parameterless constructor due to the `new()` restriction by ServiceStack. you cannot add a constructor to an interface

Comment: "I also mean a `Foo` or `Boo` object instance boxed into an `IObject` variable" - again, that ***is not boxing*** - there is no box there. But thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I just noticed boxing is whenever `object` is involved only http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that `IObject` / `IDataObject` are the same thing - otherwise it is hard to see how the call would ever work. So, the easiest thing to do is to make the caller supply the `T`:

```
public static bool AddObject<T>(this T obj) where T : IObject, new()
{
    return DataProvider.InsertObject<T>(obj, DataProvider.GetConnection());
}
```

However, this is not always workable (the caller might **only** know about `IObject`), in which case you can also get the runtime to worry about it:

```
public static bool AddObject(this IObject obj)
{
    return DataProvider.InsertObject((dynamic)obj, DataProvider.GetConnection());
}
```

The only other option is reflection via `MakeGenericMethod` / `Invoke` - messy and slow.

Frankly, I would advocate a non-generic API here. Reflection and generics do not make good friends. However, ServiceStack may not give you this luxury, in which case, the `dynamic` approach is probably your most convenient option here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with generic AddObject extension

```
public static bool AddObject<T>(this T obj) where T:IDataObject, new()
{
    return DataProvider.InsertObject(obj,DataProvider.GetConnection());
}
```

Comment: Will not combile since InsertObject requires `new()`.